# Transfer WordPress, tried everything

Tags: mysql, wordpress, installation, move, transfer

I have been struggling with this issue for hours now.
I currently have a Wordpress site running at domain.com/subdomain.
I want to transfer this to domain2.com.

What I've done:

- Exported the tables from PHPMyAdmin.
- "Replace all" from domain.com/subdomain to domain2.com in the .SQL-file. (I even used a replace tool to keep the string lengths or what not -> [WP Serialized PHP Replacer](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/))
- Downloaded the entire site from domain.com/subdomain.
- Uploaded the entire site to domain2.com.
- Changed the database info in wp-config.php to the correct info for the new DB at domain2.com.
- Imported the .SQL-file to the new database.

What happens now? Well, when I navigate to domain2.com  I get the error "Cannot display the webpage". I have tried making a brand new install of WordPress on domain2.com, and that works like a charm.

The only thing is that I got hundreds of pages and plugins with settings that I would really like to keep, took days for me just to get them in order and the clients deadline is due tomorrow.

The `Wordpress Tools > Export` tool was like a wolf in sheep clothing, tricking me into I fixed it. But it didn't copy user information or plugin settings.

Comment: Have you gone through here, step by step? http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change

Comment: You need to update the `.htaccess` too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and **NOT** like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks a lot, what a rookie mistake haha. Never transferred from subdomain to root before, thanks!